# How to limit angular digest to only effect/re-render one component/directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was developing an angular app/site, and only now realized that whenever a model changes/digest is triggered, it causes the whole page to re-render, which seems wasteful and slow.

Is there a way to cause/limit digest to only affect the directive/controller it is used in.

e.g if i have a "clock" directive with $interval to count milliseconds on a page

```
$scope.page_stats = {"ms_on_page": 0};
$interval(function() {
    $scope.page_stats.ms_on_page+= 30;
}, 30);
```

and my app layout looked like this

```
<body>
    <clock-directive></clock-directive>//<--gets rendered every 30ms
    some other html
    <some-slow-render-directive></some-slow-render-directive>
    // ^-- also gets rendered every 30ms
</body>
```

How would i stop the slow directive from updating itself/its template every 30ms , and limit the clock interval digest only to the clock directive since i know it wont be used in any other part of the page. ( this isn't my actual app, just a sample to illustrate my question)

Comment: could you show us the code of your directive..they must be using `$watch`

Comment: In my test example, im actually not using the interval value "page_stats" anywhere, at all. simply adding a running interval to any controller/directive seems to cause everything to re-render :S . In my real app, i am indeed using $watch'es

Comment: did you placed watch on either `page_stats` or `page_stats.ms_on_page`?

Comment: i didn't add a $watch to page_stats/page_stats.ms_on_page at all. I dont even have to use this variable in my template. Simply having it changed, causes all the templates of all the directives to change which is ... weird.
My real site uses $watches on object properties ( object.property_name ) and has same problem.

Comment: Could you represent your problem with a plunkr..that would be better then..

Comment: If you really need to run code that often, then I would seriously think about doing this outside of Angular. For example, a jQuery plugin could update the clock values (in HTML) and won't trigger any digests. If you needed to do some processing (say every minute, or when the clock runs out), your non-Angular code could dispatch an event that an Angular directive listens for (and then would trigger a digest using `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: @pankajparkar I'm not really sure how a Plunker would help clarify things. Using `$interval` means it will trigger a digest on every interval. Using it's plain old Javascript counterpart (`setInterval`) will not.

Comment: @SunilD. I know that..but it will only call the `watchers` on that digest cycle..thats why I'm asking for plukr..In OP case he must be doing something with watcher..by the way how can setInterval will update the bindings? in the end will need `$apply()` any case

Comment: @pankajparkar The OP says (and I believe him) that in his test example, there are no watchters. And he's asking if there's a way to stop the digest from happening on every interval. So if we know that `$interval` triggers a digest, what else is there to diagnose via a Plunker?  Also, I did mention using $apply, just one comment above m original comment to you :) PS: The answer from @Agop looks promising...

Comment: @pankajparkar You don't need watchers. Check out my Plunker. Uncomment the `$interval` version to see that the random number updates each time.

Comment: @Agop though console is saying digest cycle iteration reached limit..

Comment: Fixed, see my answer and comments for explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular will (usually) re-render everything on `$rootScope.$digest()`, which is called by `$scope.$apply()`, `$interval`, and so on.

However, there *is* an optimization strategy you can apply to only re-render the applicable portions (the high frequency updates).

First, separate your views into different scopes. For example, the counter that updates every 30 ms could be in its own controller, separating it from the scope with the heavy directive.

Then, use a non-Angular interval (e.g. `setInterval()`) to update your value, and call `$scope.$digest()` manually.

For example:

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  // this is our "heavy" calculation function
  // it displays a Unix timestamp, which should change
  // every second if the function is continously executed
  $scope.calc = function() {
    // get time in seconds
    return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  };
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.counter = 0;

  // don't use $interval, it'll call $rootScope.$apply()
  // uncomment this and comment the setInterval() call
  // to see the problem
  //$interval(function() { $scope.counter++; }, 1000);

  setInterval(function() {
    $scope.counter++;

    // digest only our scope, without re-rendering everything
    $scope.$digest();
  }, 1000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <!-- pretend this is our calculation that occurs often -->
  <p ng-controller="ChildCtrl">Interval counter: {{ counter }}</p>

  <!-- pretend this is our heavy calculation that we don't want to occur often -->
  <p>Heavy calc: {{ calc() }}</p>
</body>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iiek1WWDm2DKH2vjFiQ9)

In this case, pretend that `calc()` is the heavy directive. You'll notice that it's only evaluated once, not every time the counter updates. However, if you use `$interval`, it'll update every time the counter updates.

Note that you *must* use `$scope.$digest()` - if you use `$scope.$apply()`, it will call `$rootScope.$digest()`, which will update everything.

Further reading [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5583).

Comment: did you looked at console `[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: it seems like `$scope.$apply();` & `$scope.$digest()` giving same error..could you explain us why? I'll appreciate it..Thanks :)

Comment: @pankajparkar Fixed it, I'll update my answer. Since `Math.rand()` returns a random number, Angular kept calling it non-stop because the value never settled.

Comment: Great approach..Thanks for updating plunkr +1

Comment: FYI, if using a directive, make sure the directive is `scope: true`