# How to make angular digest only the scope of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following plunker, based on an answer in the question [How to limit angular digest to only effect/re-render one component/directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876704/how-to-limit-angular-digest-to-only-effect-re-render-one-component-directive)

JS code (omitting the controller from the original question)

```
app.directive('ngClock', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:'<span>{{date}}</span>',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      $scope.date = new Date();

      setInterval( function() {
        $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.$digest();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-controller="ChildCtrl">Interval counter: {{ date }}</p>
    <ng-clock></ng-clock>

    <!-- pretend this is our heavy calculation that we don't want to occur often -->
    <p>Heavy calc: {{ calc() }}</p>
  </body>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAkKJU8TJuzQCfRifuTW)

The call to $digest on the directives scope is not meant to 'refresh' the whole page. But it does.

Removing the `<ng-clock>` and leaving just the plain controller-based clock, works just fine. So basically, $scope.$digest within a controller correctly remains within it's scope, but for some reason, the $digest call within a directive's controller jumps outside of it's scope.

Using primarily Angular solutions, Is it possible to get a clock 'widget', or anyother frequently updating directive, to not cause a full page digest?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2595-using-scope-digest-as-a-performance-optimization-in-angularjs.htm) article, which asserts that this directive should certainly work, I realise what I am missing, in the directive:

```
scope: true
```

It works now. What threw me off was that I had debugged the directive, and I inspected it's $scope, and it certainly looked like it was it's own scope.